# Is there a way to preload TinyMCE?

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

TinyMCE is a big plugin to load at first. In nations with low bandwidth it takes minutes to load. So I am planning on preloading the tinyMCE so that the users dont have to wait for this to load.

Any Idea?

Comment: Are you loading it the default way, or with the compressor?

Comment: @Nick Craver, in any case. Does that matter?

Comment: @Starx - It really does make a difference, especially in this case.  Low bandwidth is also high latency in those nations, meaning that the many, *many* server requests to get all the TinyMCE content (scripts, plugins, stylesheets, etc) are *tremendously* improved via the compressor, since it's a few requests to the server instead of tens or hundreds to get what's needed.

Comment: @Nick Craver, I have used a compressed and jquery version

Comment: @Starx - It's not the "compressed version", I mean their compressor module/handler, available for PHP, ASPX, JSP and CFM...it's for making a single request and it batching the download of resources server-side, take a look here: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Compressor

Comment: What do you mean by 'preload'? Your users are going to have to wait for the preload anyway. Perhaps what you really want to do is make sure TinyMCE is cached and not reloaded with every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comments in this thread, perhaps this is not the solution you're looking for, but in any case here's an example of preloading [lazyloading] tinymce using jquery:

http://demos.badsyntax.co/tinymce-preload.html

Answer (score 0):

An other idea is to use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Using Ant you can get all necessary js-code (there are many some files using tinymce) in one file leading to a faster transmission.

It is in a way similar to what Nick proposed.